# How to give shadow effort on gridview item in android

Tags: android, gridview

I want to shadow effort on gridview each item.

**product_page_grid_view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
           />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/heart"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_id_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/divder_color"
       />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/products_price_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="123"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_discount_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="1891"
               />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/product_special_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="1891"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               />




            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/products_off_grid_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
             />

        </RelativeLayout>


    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:rating="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here my grid_view:-

```
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/list_product_grid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/products_page_grid_view"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:verticalSpacing="8dp"/>
```

[image]

I am new in android developing Please help me.Anyone can help me how i solve my problem.Thank in advance

Comment: use android:elevation="5dp" on GridView

Answer (score 2):

You can use elevation attribute for each view.

> android:elevation="2dp"

Answer (score 2):

For each Item of GridView you can Override the method of your own GridView Adapter and you can add the mentioned elevation to ViewGroup.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewGroup vg;

    if(convertView == null){
        vg = new RelativeLayout(mContext);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
            vg.setElevation(10);

        vg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_background);

    }
    else{
        vg = (ViewGroup) convertView;
    }

    return vg;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Create the below shape file in your drawable folder.

```
<!-- res/drawable/myrect.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Add this as your background for the item layout. and give some elevation , for me it is 2dp. change as per your design.

```
android:elevation="2dp"
android:background="@drawable/myrect"
```

This is the exact solution.